# Is there any way to make child not to evaluate?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Sorry if this is dumb but I got a spinner-wrapper which looks like this.

```
type Props = { condition: boolean; children: React.ReactNode };

export const SpinnerWrapper = ({ condition, children }: Props) => {
  return condition ? <Spinner /> : <>{children}</>;
};
```

But children evaluates nevertheless of the condition. So if it's loading child will give undefined error.
Any way to prevent this? I want to abstract the conditional rendering.

EDIT: conditional rendering works fine without the wrapper, like this

```
{isLoading ? (
        <Spinner />
      ) : (<> {some.api.data} </> )
```

But this gives api-data is undefined

```
<SpinnerWrapper condition={isLoading}>{some.api.data}</SpinnerWrapper>
```

Comment: That means the condition is never true. Can you show the parent's JSX? (also please don't add unrelated tags to your question)

Comment: added more code.

Comment: Is the initial value of `isLoading` `true`? Also, syntax matters. Your JSX up there simply renders the text "api-data" and cannot cause an undefined children error. Please provide an actual  [mre].

Comment: Any expression in JSX is evaluated during a render so it cannot cause null pointer errors. What you can do to rewrite this is to pass the data itself instead of as JSX children and render conditionally inside the spinner. However in general you cannot really about the conditional rendering.

Comment: i see. thanks for the answer, but it's not really what i'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your children are evaluated in the parent Component in this manner:

```
<SpinnerWrapper>
    <children1 />
    <children2 />
    ...
</SpinnerWrapper>
```

Instead, you want to conditionally show the spinner with no children when it's loading and with children when it's not.

```
isLoading ?
    <SpinnerWrapper /> : 
    <SpinnerWrapper>
        <children1 />
        <children2 />
        ...
    </SpinnerWrapper>
```

If you do not want to do this, you probably have to re-study the way you are rendering your components.

Comment: I figured that out. My question is is it possible to make the first code work? I don't wanna pollute my code with lots of {isLoading ? : }

Comment: Well, what you probably need is to change this line of code from
<SpinnerWrapper condition={isLoading}>{some.api.data}</SpinnerWrapper>
to
<SpinnerWrapper condition={isLoading}>{some?.api?.data}</SpinnerWrapper>

and the props from
type Props = { condition: boolean; children: React.ReactNode };

to
type Props = { condition: boolean; children?: React.ReactNode };

Note: I've just added some '?' to tell typescript this could be undefined

Comment: looks like there is no clean way about this

Comment: @PapaXVII well it depends what clean for you is, anyway I agree with you.
I don't like conditional rendering in React as well, but I've learned to cope with it